# How to select element only without its child?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, selector

Let's say I have a `div` with `id="main"` that contains multi-level random elements random elements:

```
 <div id="main">
    Main text
    <div>Random element
         <a>Random element
            <p>Random element</p>
         </a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

How do I target the content of `#main` only without all of its childs which is `"Main text"`?

Comment: With `#main` you *are* only selecting the top-level element, but the child elements are inheriting *some* properties. For example, try setting a border on `#main` - it won't be applied to all children.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, to work properly, you should make some changes in your HTML structure. So, using the CSS selectors, you can correctly select the target. Something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <p>Main text</p>
    <div class="random">
        <p>random text</p>
        <p>random text</p>
        <a href="#">
            <p>random text</p>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main > p {
    color: red;
}
```